# What is the reason that the Loss function returns a negative value?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I make a CNN model for an intrusion detection system with Keras. I have a problem with my loss result. How to fix my code, please.
And these are the shapes of the dataset:

```
x_train shape: (1131151, 79)
y_train shape: (1131151, 2)
x_test shape: (53386, 79)
y_test shape: (53386, 2)
train shape after reshape: (1131151, 79, 1)
test shape after reshape: (53386, 79, 1)
```

My **Model** is:

```
model = Sequential()

#convolution 1st layer

model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=(filter_size), padding="same",
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(droprate))
          
#convolution 2nd layer
model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(filter_size), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(droprate))

#convolution 3rd layer
model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=(filter_size), activation='relu', padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(droprate))

#FCN 1st layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,use_bias=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(droprate))

#FCN 2nd layer
model.add(Dense(32,use_bias=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(droprate))

#FCN 3rd layer
model.add(Dense(16,use_bias=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(droprate))

#FCN final layer
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="Adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

My results are:

```
score = model.evaluate(X_test, preprocess.y_test, verbose=0)
Test loss: 9.198558109346777e-05
Test accuracy: 0.9999812841415405
```

As you can see the loss function is negative and the accuracy is near to 100%
What is the problem in my code?

Comment: `9.198558109346777e-05` is not a negative number....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the number, I think it was negative. The problem still exists, right?

Comment: What is your distribution of the train/test y-label? If there is a large class imbalance (say 99% of training examples are `false`='no intrusion', then the classifier can learn to always predict no intrusion and be 99 % accurate.

Comment: The problem only exists when you prove to us that it exists, including which exact numbers you are seeing.

Comment: @TC 80% for training and 20% for testing

Comment: No I’m not asking about the train/test split. I’m asking about the distribution of ground truth labels. What fraction are true and what fraction are false?

Comment: I have 14 types of attacks, each attack I give it numbers 1(Intrusion) and 0 for benign (no intrusion). Is this what you mean by your question?
I hope I answered your question.

Comment: The class distribution is the % of your samples that fall in each class (intrusion, no intrusion). If lets say,  80% of the total samples belong to no intrusion class, then you are facing class imbalance, like @TCArlen said.

Answer (score 1):

Test loss: 9.198558109346777e-05
The value is not negative. This is the scientific form of 10 to the power -5 or 0.00009198558.

Comment: It is actually 10 to the power of -5.